# Array size in nawk

Tags: arrays, nawk

I am reading [Introduction to Arrays](http://people.cs.uu.nl/piet/docs/nawk/nawk_toc.html#TOC83) for **nawk**

It says:

> Arrays in awk superficially resemble arrays in other programming
>   languages; but there are fundamental differences. In awk, you don't
>   need to specify the size of an array before you start to use it.

Then whats the limit of members I can have in that array? How do I know that? And is this error-pron? (because I know it cannot be infinite :D)

Comment: Nope, probably depends on your memory space.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, you are right. Just wondering what would be the behavior when we cross this limit. (Other than the system crashes with a blast in fumes and you can die)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nawk has limits on various things from experience although I have no idea what they are and can't find a reference.  gawk however doesn't so if you want security against hitting limits, try gawk.  Ref here:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/unixnut3/chapter/ch11.html#ch11_09.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I believe its not defined and depends on system resources.

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum size since in Awk arrays are allowed to grow and shrink as necessary. It is limited by your PC.